# How do I clear Command bindings registered by CommandManager?

Tags: c#, wpf, commandbinding

I have this control (WPF) that uses a CommandBinding and it gets registered like this:

```
CommandBinding binding = new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Delete, OnDeleteExecuted, CanExecuteDelete);
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(MyObject), binding);
```

So, when I unload the control, I want to clear this binding. How would I go about that?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511674/set-command-target-to-template-part/21515179#21515179

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[**BindingOperations.ClearBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.clearbinding.aspx)

Comment: Would BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(this); be better for this case?

Comment: If you're in the context of the control, then yes. You could instantly clear all the bindings for that control.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way. @Carlo asked about CommandBinding on CommandManager, which has nothing to do with BindingBase...

Comment: What kind of answer is this? This should not have any up votes.

Answer (score 5):

If the scope of the Commands is a concrete UIElement, you should better use:

- Register a CommandBinding: myUIelement.CommandBindings.Add(myCommand);
- Unregister a CommandBinding: myUIelement.CommandBindings.Remove(myCommand);
- Unregister all CommandBindings: myUIelement.CommandBindings.Clear();

I hope this helps.